# Replacing empty values in a CSV with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

my CSV contains the following data:

[image]

CSV in plain text:

```
System Speed Dialling Number,"Name (20 characters)","CO Line Access Number + Telephone Number (32 digits)","CLI Destination" 
0,"USER1","Dial=00123456300","Dial=" 
1,"USER2","Dial=00123456400","Dial=" 
2,"","","" 
3,"","","" 
4,"","","" 
5,"","","" 
6,"","","" 
7,"","","" 
8,"","","" 
9,"","","" 
10,"","",""
```

Up to 1000 rows.

I tried using the following script to replace the empty values ​​in the "*CO Line Access Number + Telephone Number (32 digits)*" and "*CLI Destination*" columns:

```
$dial1 = import-csv C:\TEMP\dial.csv
$dial1 | foreach-object {
$_.'CO Line Access Number + Telephone Number (32 digits)' = $_.'CO Line Access Number + Telephone Number (32 digits)'.replace("","Dial=") 
}
$dial1 | export-csv C:\TEMP\dial.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

**Error:** The string cannot be zero-length

**Question:** Is there a way to fill the columns mentioned using a script and the value "Dial="

*Sorry I have no experience with this...*

---

Alternatively, I thought of a script that writes only the lines with users from one CSV to another CSV (ex. where "Name (20 Characters)" isn´t empty). Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: Can you update your question including the CSV as plain text instead of a screenshot?

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to insert `Dial=` in the `CO Line Access Number + Telephone Number (32 digits)` __if the value is an empty / null string__. Is this correct ?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this logic to accomplish it, check if the value on the column `CO Line Access Number + Telephone Number (32 digits)` is a null or whitespace string using [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-7.0), if the condition
evaluates to `$true`, re-assign the desired value (`Dial=`) to that property.

```bash
Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.'CO Line Access Number + Telephone Number (32 digits)')) {
        $_.'CO Line Access Number + Telephone Number (32 digits)' = 'Dial='
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv newfixedcsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

To briefly explain the error, [`.Replace($oldValue, $newValue)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0#system-string-replace(system-string-system-string)) complains because the argument for `$oldValue` **cannot be an empty string (`''` or `[string]::Empty` or `[NullString]::Value`)**.